# Ensuring SLA with Mesos and privileged tasks

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

What if I run a Mesos cluster, with both development and say, mission critical applications. Is it possible to have "privileged" task to be executed in the cluster for these type of cases, and even have nodes shut down lesser privileged services to make sure the privileged service gets processing power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no notion of privileged tasks in Mesos (`0.24.1` at the time of writing). *Preemption* is likely an upcoming feature to be introduced to support other features such as *Quota* and *Optimistic Offers*. However, there are **reserved resources** in which critical tasks can run on.

Resources can be reserved for a **role**, and frameworks are registered under a certain role. For example, if a framework `F` registers under role `R`, `F` receives resources with role `*` (i.e. unreserved) as well as resources with role `R` (i.e. reserved for `R`).

The privileged tasks then would be launched on these reserved resources. Since reserved resources are only offered to the frameworks in the role, the resources will be available for the relaunch of the critical task even if the critical task were to crash.

**NOTE:** Since many frameworks can register under `R`, you can assign `R` uniquely to `F` to grant it sole ownership of the resources (Refer to `register_frameworks` under [Authorization](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/authorization/)).

Refer to [Reservation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/reservation/) documentation for further information